# Anonymous function in function composition

Tags: r, operators

While reading Function operator chapter in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html) by H. Wickham, I came across the `compose` function. Infix operator, "o" is used to create function composition:

```
library(pryr)
"%o%" <- compose
```

Now the question is, why does the following function works

`mul <- sum %o% median %o% mean %o% length %o% function(x) x ^ 2`

`mul(1:10)`

`10`

But this doesnt

`mul <- sum %o% median %o% mean %o% function(x) x ^ 2 %o% length`

`mul(1:10)`

`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'list(...)[[1L]]' is not a function, character or symbol`

where the only difference is the position of the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the anonymous function needs to be put in braces, otherwise `length` is composed as part of the function, and this (legitimately) returns an error. You can try:

```
mul2 <- sum %o% median %o% mean %o% {function(x) x ^ 2} %o% length
> mul2(1:10)
[1] 100
```

Is this what you want?